# how to echo text not value

Tags: php, html, echo

I am attempting to echo the name of a selected dropdown rather than its value. I understand that echoing a dropdown's value can be achieved by implementing something such as:

```
$no2 = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
echo $no2;
```

where vehicleStyle is the  name.

this is my code

```
<select name="vehicleStyle">
<option value="2">Volvo</option>
<option value="3">Saab</option>
<option value="4">Fiat</option>
<option value="5">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If I add

```
    $no2 = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
    echo $no2;
```

to my code, I get either 2,3,4 or 5 (whichever is selected). How can I echo the dropdown name, either volvo, saab , fiat or audi?

**NOTE:** i use this code

```
    $no2 = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
    echo $no2;
```

to show the price of the car which i set in value, but also i need to echo the text to show the name of the car, how i can do that?

Comment: you have some confusion... what is sent to the server is the VALUE of an input, not "the text inside it".

Comment: The option name is only for presentation in the HTML. It isn't sent with the form. If you need the name, then put that as the value instead. If you need both, you need to add both as the value (either separate it somehow: `name;id` and explode it on the back end, or pass the value as a json object. `value='{"name": "Volvo","id":2}'`),

Comment: if you need both, you have to manage it in other ways

Comment: Change the `value` of the option to the text, unless you need the numeric ID

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need the values (2, 3, 4, 5), you can just use:

```
<select name="vehicleStyle">
<option>Volvo</option>
<option>Saab</option>
<option>Fiat</option>
<option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

but if you need both, you should do something like this:

```
$no2 = [
  "2" => "Volvo",
  "3" => "Saab",
  "4" => "Fiat",
  "5" => "Audi"
]$_POST['vehicleStyle'];
echo $no2;
```

be aware that if you change the dropdown in the future, you have to come back here and change also this array

Comment: I believe you missed a set of brackets around the post value.

Comment: _“you have to come back here and change also this array”_ - which would make a good point for not having the select field “static” then, but to build it _from_ this array ;-)

Comment: Also it's a good idea to have vehicleStyle list in a database table. That way you can manage it without needing to change your code. First, you need to change your code to work with the list taken from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach is give the value the same as the text in it!

```html
<form method="post">
    <select name="vehicleStyle">
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="vehicleName">
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['vehicleName'])){
    echo $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also need both text(*name*) and value(*id*) as [magnus eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432) Suggest you need to separate them like: *id;name* and explode it on the back end to get *id* as well as *name*.

```html
<form method="post">
    <select name="vehicleStyle">
        <option value="2;Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="3;Saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="4;Fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="5;Audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="vehicleName">
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['vehicleName'])){
    list($id, $name) = explode(';', $_POST['vehicleStyle']);
    echo $id.' => '.$name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

i solved this by editing the code to:

```
<form method="post">
<select name="vehicleName">
<option value="2|volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="3|saab">Saab</option>
<option value="4|fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="5|audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$no2=$_POST['vehicleName'];
$no2_explode=explode('|', $no2);
```

for text

```
<?php echo $no2_explode[1]; ?>
```

and  for the price number

```
<?php echo $no2_explode[0]; ?>
```